# Notifications ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently I have a notification system when a patients fills out a form they request a signature from a doctor. The doctor gets notified successfully. But what I am looking for is when the doctor gets the notification they can click on it (link_to) and be redirected automatically to the form.

```
<% if @notifications.count > 0 %>
  <ul>
    <% @notifications.each do |notification| %>
      <li>
        <span class="notification-title"><%= notification.title %></span>
        <span class="notification-message"><%= notification.message %></span>
        <span class="notification-time"><%= notification.created_at.strftime("%B %e at %l:%m%P") %></span>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
  <div class="notifications-preview-footer">
    <%= link_to "See All", notifications_path %>
  </div>
<% else %>
  <ul>
    <li>No Notifications</li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed your title span with link_to sample, so if the title clicked then it will go to notification show page

```
<% if @notifications.count > 0 %>
  <ul>
    <% @notifications.each do |notification| %>
      <li>
        <%= link_to <span class="notification-title"><%= notification.title %></span>, notification_path(notification)  %>
        <span class="notification-message"><%= notification.message %></span>
        <span class="notification-time"><%= notification.created_at.strftime("%B %e at %l:%m%P") %></span>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
  <div class="notifications-preview-footer">
    <%= link_to "See All", notifications_path %>
  </div>
<% else %>
  <ul>
    <li>No Notifications</li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of unknowns here, first you routes.rb file needs to have the routes defined to allow this say maybe

```
# config/routes.rb

resources: notifications
```

Then in you need to define the controller actions for a view maybe show/edit?

```
 # notifications_controller.rb

 class NotificationsController < ApplicationController

   def show
     @notification = Notification.find(params[:id])
   end
 end
```

Then you could modify you view like above to allow a link to each notification

```
<% @notifications.each do |notification| %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to <span class="notification-title"><%= notification.title %></span>, notification_path(notification)  %>
    <span class="notification-message"><%= notification.message %></span>
    <span class="notification-time"><%= notification.created_at.strftime("%B %e at %l:%m%P") %></span>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

This may get you what you're looking for.